# How can I plot log2 fold-change across genome coordinates (using Deseq2 output csv)

Tags: python, r, rna-seq

I have RNA-seq data (3 replicates for 2 different treatments) from a bacterial genome and have used DeSeq2 to calculate the log2fc for genes (padj < 0.05). This generates a csv file that includes (but is not limited to) the gene name and the log2fc[example of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wyUN.png).

update: The genome is published and annotated, so I have the corresponding genomic coordinates for each gene. Perhaps its as simple as merging this information. But not all the genes are differentially expressed, so it gets more complicated...

However, I would like to log2 RNA change (y axis) vs genomic coordinates (x axis). But I scoured the internet with no success. Does anyone know of a relatively simple way to do this? I'm happy to use R/python... I have included an example from a paper for what I am after...  [example of what I'm after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLyz5.png)

Perhaps this is so simple that thats why no one talks about it. but in the image I have attached, they dont discuss how they plotted it.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: how do you get genomic coordinates from the information you've given?

Comment: I have a separate bed file with the list of genes and corresponding coordinates. So I feel I should be able to merge this information into one file. I have updated the original question to include this. Sorry

Comment: You can load the bedfile as a GRanges object using `rtracklayer::import`, and then convert the GRanges to a dataframe with `as.data.frame`. You can then merge the two data.frames using `merge` or `dplyr::left_join`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use an example to get DESeq2 results:

```
library(DESeq2)
library(zebrafishRNASeq)
data(zfGenes)

head(zfGenes)
                   Ctl1 Ctl3 Ctl5 Trt9 Trt11 Trt13
ENSDARG00000000001  304  129  339  102    16   617
ENSDARG00000000002  605  637  406   82   230  1245
ENSDARG00000000018  391  235  217  554   451   565
ENSDARG00000000019 2979 4729 7002 7309  9395  3349

dds = DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(zfGenes[rowMeans(zfGenes)>30,],
data.frame(grp=gsub("[0-9]*","",colnames(zfGenes))),~grp)
dds = DESeq(dds)

res = data.frame(results(dds))
```

We need to get an annotation, can be a bed file, you use the same function `import()` from rtracklayer:

```
library(rtracklayer)
gtf = import("ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-100/gtf/danio_rerio/Danio_rerio.GRCz11.100.gtf.gz")

genes = gtf[gtf$type=="gene"]

head(genes)
GRanges object with 6 ranges and 20 metadata columns:
      seqnames      ranges strand |   source     type     score     phase
         <Rle>   <IRanges>  <Rle> | <factor> <factor> <numeric> <integer>
  [1]        4 17308-18211      - |  ensembl     gene      <NA>      <NA>
  [2]        4 31259-45642      + |  ensembl     gene      <NA>      <NA>
  [3]        4 38344-45396      + |  ensembl     gene      <NA>      <NA>
  [4]        4 48519-53370      - |  ensembl     gene      <NA>      <NA>
  [5]        4 57034-64703      - |  ensembl     gene      <NA>      <NA>
  [6]        4 69619-72011      + |  ensembl     gene      <NA>      <NA>
```

You need to match the rownames of the deseq2 results to the column, in this case it is gene_id, if your table is in symbols, match it to the appropriate one:

```
annotation = as.data.frame(genes)[match(rownames(res),genes$gene_id),]
head(as.data.frame(genes)[match(rownames(res),genes$gene_id),])
      seqnames    start      end width strand         source type score phase
12565        9 34112067 34121839  9773      - ensembl_havana gene    NA    NA
12564        9 34089156 34113209 24054      + ensembl_havana gene    NA    NA
484          4 15081385 15103696 22312      - ensembl_havana gene    NA    NA
480          4 15011341 15059876 48536      + ensembl_havana gene    NA    NA
21778       12 33484458 33537126 52669      + ensembl_havana gene    NA    NA
```

There are more than one chromosome here so let's just do chromosome 25:

```
res = cbind(res,annotation[,1:5])
res = res[which(res$seqnames == 25),]

plot(res$start,res$log2FoldChange,xaxt="n",xlab="Pos on chr25",ylab="Log2FC")
axis(side=1,5e6*1:8,paste(5 * 1:8,"Mb"))
```

[image]